# Python Split itertools output to multi files(BIG output)

Tags: python-3.x

So I have created a script to read lines from a file (1500 lines)

Write them as 10 per line 
(and do every possible output we can get with product a b c d a , a b c d b etc...)

The thing is the moment I run the script my computer freezes completly(because it writes so much data)

So I thought if its possible to run the script every 100 mb it will save it to a file and save the current state so when I run the script again it will actuly run from where we stopped (the last line on the 100mb file)

Or if you have another solution I would love to hear it :P

heres the script  :

```
from itertools import product

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
comb = product(content, repeat=10)
new_content = [elem for elem in list(comb)]
with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in new_content:
        f.write(str(line) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
new_content = [elem for elem in list(comb)]
```

takes the generator and transforms it into a list in memory, twice. The result is the same as just doing

```
new_content = list(comb)
```

Your computer freezes up because this will use all of the available RAM.
Since you use new_content only for iterating over it, you could just iterate over the initial generator directly instead:

```
from itertools import product

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
comb = product(content, repeat=10)
with open('log.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in comb:
        f.write(str(line) + '\n')
```

But now this will fill up your harddisk, since with an input size of 1500 lines it will produce 57665039062500000000000000000000 lines (1500**10) of output.

Comment: Thank you for the response that worked!, I have a second question how can I clean the output because it outputs the Tupple as str so i get ('1', '2',) When I want the out put to be clear as 1 2 3

Comment: @Teeext try using `' '.join(line)` instead of `str(line)`

Comment: I fixed it by doing like so : f.write('\n' + ' '.join(x.rstrip('\n') for x in line))

Answer (score 0):

I would open the file in a separate function and yield a line at a time - that way you're never going to blow your memory.

```
function read_file(filename):
    with open(filename", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

Then you can use this in your code:

```
for line in read_file("log.txt"):
    f.write(line + "\n")
```